# Why is jquery.validation.js not working in my project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am currently learning jQuery and using jquery.validate.js to validate a form field on the client side. The thing is that I can't get any output.

I have looked at the console; I target the an input field and dumped its attribute to console and it worked, when I use jquery.validate.js though, nothing.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Validate</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form id="register">
      <h2 class="display-4 mb-4">Registration Form</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email address" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary mt-5" id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Sign Up" role="button">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script src="validation.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#register").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    messages: {
      required: 'You have to enter a valid email address',
      email: 'You rmail is not valid'
    }
  });
});
```

Any help concerning the subject is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for your `validate()` method settings isn't quite right. There is no `name="required"` element in the DOM. That property should be under `email`, like this:

```
$("#register").validate({
  debug: true, // remember to remove this after testing :)
  rules: {
    email: { 
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    email: {
      required: 'You have to enter a valid email address'
    }
  }
});
```